# How to pass array'method signature C#

Tags: c#, expression

Now I have a ConcurrentDictionary . 
I want to invoke the IDataExchangeServiceCallBack's method.

the IDataExchangeServiceCallBack's code below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataExchangeServiceCallBack
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SendResult(string msg);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Receive(List<RealDataModel> models);
}
```

In other class, I want invoke dict's method foreach.

such as

```
    public void Receive(List<RealDataModel> models)
    {
        Broast(o => nameof(o.Receive), models);
    }

    public void SendResult(string msg)
    {
        Broast(o => nameof(o.SendResult), msg);
    }
```

And Broast method below:

```
    private void Broast(Func<IDataExchangeServiceCallBack, string> funcMethodName, params object[] args)
    {
        if (_callbackChannelList.Count > 0)
        {
            var callbackChannels = _callbackChannelList.ToArray();

            foreach (var channel in callbackChannels)
            {
                try
                {
                    var type = channel.Value.GetType();

                    // fetch the method's name.
                    var methodName = funcMethodName.Invoke(channel.Value);

                    // reflect & get the method
                    var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);

                    //invoke
                    methodInfo?.Invoke(channel.Value, args);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _callbackChannelList.TryRemove(channel.Key, out _);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my question is how to implement above code without reflect, it's there any better solution.

The Expression can implement it ?

I'm not familiar with Expression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how you got to the solution you have. Regardless of the type of `o`, the expression, for example, `nameof(o.Receive)` will always result in the string `"Receive"`. It seems to me you could just pass `nameof(IDataExchangeServiceCallBack.Receive)` to the method instead of passing a delegate.

That said, I also don't understand why you are looking to use reflection *or* `Expression`. It appears to me that, at the call site, you know the type of object you're dealing with, the method you want to call, *and* the arguments you want to pass. So you could just pass a delegate that does all that. For example:

```
private void Broast(Action<IDataExchangeServiceCallBack> callback)
{
    foreach (var channel in _callbackChannelList.ToArray())
    {
        try
        {
            //invoke
            callback(channel.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _callbackChannelList.TryRemove(channel.Key, out _);
        }
    }

}
```

Used like:

```
public void Receive(List<RealDataModel> models)
{
    Broast(o => o.Receive(models));
}

public void SendResult(string msg)
{
    Broast(o => o.SendResult(msg));
}
```

Note that I've cleaned up the `Broast()` method a bit. There's very little overhead calling `ToArray()` on an empty collection, and it simplifies the code significantly to remove the `Count > 0` check. Code is always easier to write and read later if you can remove unnecessary conditional checks.